# Turn Based Strategy Game techniques

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, actionscript

I want to make a turn base strategy game. I was just curious if anyone had any sources or books that explains the concept and architect of designing a turn based strategy game or any turn based game. thanks!

Comment: You need more information. Is it played by more than one person? If so, do they share a computer? Or Is it over the net?

Answer (score 3):

Don't know if this is what you're looking for, but I've been meaning to give this article a close look:

[Battlefield Simulator](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/game/BattleField.aspx)

The catch: it's in C#

It's a turned based wargame that features an AI opponent for one or both sides, terrain tiles which affects movement and variety of unit types.  It looks impressive but I haven't had a look at the code.

Answer (score 1):

There's a series of books with short articles on Game AI ([1](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1584500778), [2](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1584502894), [3](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1584504579), [4](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1584505230)). You might be able to find one or more at a local library too.

Comment: might have to take a look at those. have you read any of them. Could I reference them with any language ?

Comment: They're about concepts, so they can apply to any language. But the other side of that is that they won't tell you how to write your game, just how to implement certain techniques.

Comment: I've read parts of them. I wanted to know specific things about designing a realtime strategy game. My local library has 3 of the 4 and I simply checked them out. Some articles have actual code, but most just talk about concepts and very generic pseudo-code.